# Generated list with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have generated a list using PHP with elements selected from a database. It works perfectly fine. But the problem is when I try to get `li` index with jquery it only gives me odd index. Like when I click on the first element it gives these indices:

```
home(index 0: it should be 0)
    ,about(index 2: actually it should be 1)
    ,about(index 4: actually it should be 2)
    ,about(index 6: actually it should be 3)
    ,about(index 8: actually it should be 4)
    ,about(index 10: actually it should be 5).
```

I have used while loop to generate this `id`.

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>

            <li class="list-group-item"><?=$row['name']?><li>

        <?php endwhile ?>
    </ul>

JS:

$('ul li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log(index);
})
```

Comment: please post some relevant code / html too to understand the problem. Also specify what exactly is your goal by correcting the indexes

Answer (score 0):

You have put `<li>` (opening tag) instead of `</li>` (closing tag) in your html. please correct it and it will solve your issue and gives you correct index

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>

            <li class="list-group-item"><?=$row['name']?></li>

        <?php endwhile ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: happy to help you :). you can accept and upvote the answer if find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hack to make it works you should `fetchAll` and use `for` loop

```
 <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <?php $i = 0; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):?>

                <li class="list-group-item" data-index="$i" ><?=$row['name']?><li>

            <?php $i++ ; endwhile ?>
        </ul>


$('ul li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index');
    console.log(index);
})
```